# What is the size of this class and Why?

Tags: c++, class, sizeof

I have two classes as follows

```
class A
{

};

class B
{
    int a[];
};


int main()
{
    cout << sizeof(A) <<endl;      //outputs 1
    cout << sizeof(B) <<endl;      //outputs 0
    return 0;
}
```

I am familiar that size of empty class is 1,but why is the size of class B coming to be ZERO??

Comment: The class `B` shouldn't compile.

Comment: §8.3.4.1 If the constant-expression (5.19) is present, it shall be an integral constant expression and its value shall be greater than zero.

Comment: @pushE Which compiler are you using and which version?

Comment: Also, `cout` isn't something you wrote yourself there, is it? I mean, I see no evidence of the std namespace being used...

Answer (score 6):

GCC permits zero length arrays as an extension: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html

And:

> As a quirk of the original implementation of zero-length arrays, sizeof evaluates to zero.

Comment: That would explain `sizeof(B::a)` being 0. I dont think it excuses `sizeof(B)` being 0.

Comment: I guess you'd have to take that up with the gcc developers.  The OP isn't lying about the results.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is ill-formed as far as C++ language is concerned. In particular, the class `B` shouldn't compile in C++ Standard Conformant compiler. Your compiler has either bug, or it provides this feature as extension.

GCC with `-pedantic-errors -std=c++11` gives this error:

```
cpp.cpp:18:11: error: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array 'a' [-Wpedantic]
     int a[];
           ^
```

Comment: @thomas: please compile it with `-std=c++11 -pedantic-errors`, then let us know.

Comment: i compiled it in VS2010 and it is giving 1,1

Answer (score 2):

The size of an empty class is not 1. It's **AT LEAST** 1 in a C++ system.
The reason is that you need to be able for example to allocate an instance with `new` and having a non-null pointer directed at it.

The second case instead is simply invalid C++.

Often compiler makers take some freedom by allowing non-standard "extensions" by default and try to make you use them unconsciously (a paranoid would say to lock you in by making your code unportable to other compilers).